# Force WordPress live preview to reload

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have some elements that are loaded into my home page if the option to do so is set in the theme customizer. When adding the control to the theme customizer to display the element I have set transport to postMessage so the preview does not reload when the option is changed. In the javascript file I am using to update the preview in real time, when the option to display the extra elements is changed I am checking weather or not the elements have been loaded and if they have I use fadeIn and `fadeOut` to remove or add the elements, however if they have not been loaded I will need to force the preview to reload using jquery as the elements will not yet exist to `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`. Below is my jquery so far...

```
wp.customize( 'element_show', function( value ) {
  value.bind( function( newval ) {
    if($(".element").length == 0){
      //elements are not loaded so need to reload the live preview on change to load the elements, this is where I am stuck
    }
    else{
      //elements are loaded so it is just a case of using fadeIn and fadeOut
      if(newval == 'yes'){
        $(".element").fadeIn();
      }
      else{
        $(".element").fadeOut();
      }
    }
  } );
} );
```

I hope that makes sense, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to force refresh the preview pane in customizer :

```
wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
```

Final code

```
wp.customize( 'element_show', function( value ) {
value.bind( function( newval ) {
if($(".element").length == 0){
  wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
}
else{
  if(newval == 'yes'){
    $(".element").fadeIn();
  }
  else{
    $(".element").fadeOut();
  }
}
} );
} );
```